# Can Johnson's algorithm for simple cycles be modified in order to find only cycles up to length L (but all of them)?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a question regarding Johnson’s algorithm for finding all simple cycles in a graph.

I was wondering it is possible to modify the algorithm in order to find only cycles up to a given length.

After having read into the algorithm, my approach would the following:

Assume I want only cycles up to length L.
Then, if the stack has reached height L, if the current node on top of the stack is not a neighbor of the starting node, I treat it as having no neighbors left, i.e. I remove it again from the stack.

I am not deep enough into network theory, however, to be sure that this modification still guarantees me finding all simple cycles (up to length L).